# How to cut animation short

Tags: javascript

I have a div that moves on keydown events in js.
It keeps moving for a certain time after key is released.
How do I have the animation stop immediately on release?

The animation is in a switch statement with char codes, can I use a keyup function in the switch?

```
 $(".sprite2").hide();

    $(document).keydown(function(key) {
        switch(key.which) {

            // a
            case 65:
                $(".sprite2").hide();
                $(".sprite").show();
                $(".sprite").animate({left: "-=10px"}, 'fast');
                $(".sprite2").animate({left: "-=10px"}, 'fast');
                break;

            // w
            case    87:
                $(".sprite").animate({top: "-=10px"}, 'fast');
                $(".sprite2").animate({top: "-=10px"}, 'fast');
                break;

            // d
            case 68:
                $(".sprite2").show();
                $(".sprite").hide();
                $(".sprite2").animate({left: "+=10px"}, 'fast');
                $(".sprite").animate({left: "+=10px"}, 'fast');
        break;

            // s
            case 83:
                $(".sprite").animate({top: "+=10px"}, 'fast');
                $(".sprite2").animate({top: "+=10px"}, 'fast');
                break;

            case onkeyup: 
                $(".sprite").animate()
        }
    });
});
```

The 'sprite' is the html element(s).

I couldn't seem to get .add/removeClass to work so I overcame this by adding a second one and hiding the one I didn't want shown.

They're the same but one reflected horizontally when animating in the opposite direction (to look as though walking forward).

Comment: The animation moves the div ({direction: "+/-=10px"}, 'fast');

Comment: Maybe [`stop()`](https://api.jquery.com/stop/) or [`finish()`](https://api.jquery.com/finish/) ?

Comment: Can we see the animation code? What are you using to perform the animation? e.g. jQuery.animate, Velocity/Transit.js/GreenSock/something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the CSS property of the div, instead of using an animation.
Update the position by adding the amount of pixels you want it to move on key down with it's current position.

Or even better. Here is an example of animating in a certain direction on different key presses with a switch statement: [JQuery Example](http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=faq&file=jquery-move-an-element-using-left-right-up-and-down-arrow-keys)

**Code from the above link:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>jQuery Move an Element to Left/Right/Up/Down Using Arrow Keys</title>
<style type="text/css">
    .box{
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        position: relative;
        margin: 200px auto 0;
        background: url("../images/mushroom.jpg") yellowgreen;
    }
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    switch (e.which){
    case 37:    //left arrow key
        $(".box").finish().animate({
            left: "-=50"
        });
        break;
    case 38:    //up arrow key
        $(".box").finish().animate({
            top: "-=50"
        });
        break;
    case 39:    //right arrow key
        $(".box").finish().animate({
            left: "+=50"
        });
        break;
    case 40:    //bottom arrow key
        $(".box").finish().animate({
            top: "+=50"
        });
        break;
    }
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <p><strong>Note:</strong> Click inside the output viewport and press the arrow keys to move the box.</p>
    <div class="box"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is very similar to what I have already done. Though my code doesn't have .finish()

What does finish do?

What I'm trying to achieve is to have the image move while the key is held and stop on release, similar to a character in a game.

Thank you.

Comment: @OliverBeach `finish()` and `stop()` are both ways of prematurely ending animations. There are links to the documentation of both in the comments on your question :)